# Undefined array_key Laravel PHP

Tags: multidimensional-array, laravel-8

I'm sending this kind of data to view blade.

Array of data from controller to view

[image: Array of data from controller to view]

When I'm trying to access to the values, its said undefined array_key 'from_to'.

```
 @for($i=0; $i<count($contents); $i++)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $i++ }}</td> //No
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $contents[$i]['from_to'] }}</td> //From-to
        @foreach($range as $ranges)
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $contents[$i]['quantity'] }}</td> //Qty
            <td style="text-align: center;">{{ $contents[$i]['sales'] }}</td> //Sales
        @endforeach
    </tr>
@endfor
```

What exactly is the problem here? Please help me

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why not use a `foreach` loop for the `$contents` variable? You could also dump `$contents[$i]` to inspect the content within that `for` loop

Comment: I did change it to 'foreach' , and still showing the same error, 'undefined array_key from_to'. Then to see the content of it, i did 'dd($contents[0])'  the array showing the same with the pic i inserted. That's why i'm not seeing any wrong in the way i'm accessing it.